Invalid value may be returned when invoking overloaded bit operators for scoped enumeration type
The code snippet is used recorded the status of several cameras. And I overload several bit operators for the said scoped enumeration.
The code snippet works below well.
Though I clearly know that there would be no overflow problem at all, I am still worried about the expresson of MODULE_ENABLED::MODULE_ENABLED_FRONT_CAMERA|MODULE_ENABLED::MODULE_ENABLED_MIDDLE_CAMERA
as the result of the said expresson not a valid value for enum class MODULE_ENABLED. Is there any potential problem lie behind?
I have carefully read the related question posted on SO and SE, but they do not clearly answer my question.
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

enum class MODULE_ENABLED : uint8_t
{
    MODULE_ENABLED_NONE = 0,
    MODULE_ENABLED_FRONT_CAMERA = 1,
    MODULE_ENABLED_MIDDLE_CAMERA = 2,
    MODULE_ENABLED_BACK_CAMERA = 4,
};

MODULE_ENABLED operator|(const MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b);
MODULE_ENABLED& operator|=(MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b);
MODULE_ENABLED operator&(const MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b);
MODULE_ENABLED operator&=(MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b);
MODULE_ENABLED operator^(const MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b);
MODULE_ENABLED& operator^=(MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b);
MODULE_ENABLED operator~(const MODULE_ENABLED& a);


MODULE_ENABLED operator|(const MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b)
{
    using MODULE_ENABLED = MODULE_ENABLED;
    
    return static_cast<MODULE_ENABLED>(static_cast<std::underlying_type<MODULE_ENABLED>::type>(a) | static_cast<std::underlying_type<MODULE_ENABLED>::type>(b));
}

MODULE_ENABLED& operator|=(MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b)
{
    a=(a|b);
    return a;
}

MODULE_ENABLED operator&(const MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b)
{
    using MODULE_ENABLED = MODULE_ENABLED;

    return static_cast<MODULE_ENABLED>(static_cast<std::underlying_type<MODULE_ENABLED>::type>(a) & static_cast<std::underlying_type<MODULE_ENABLED>::type>(b));
}

MODULE_ENABLED operator&=(MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b)
{
    a = a&b;
    return a;
}

MODULE_ENABLED operator^(const MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b)
{
    using MODULE_ENABLED = MODULE_ENABLED;

    return static_cast<MODULE_ENABLED>(static_cast<std::underlying_type<MODULE_ENABLED>::type>(a) ^ static_cast<std::underlying_type<MODULE_ENABLED>::type>(b));
}

MODULE_ENABLED& operator^=(MODULE_ENABLED& a, const MODULE_ENABLED& b)
{
    a = a ^ b;
    return a;
}

MODULE_ENABLED operator~(const MODULE_ENABLED& a)
{
    using MODULE_ENABLED = MODULE_ENABLED;
    return static_cast<MODULE_ENABLED>(~static_cast<std::underlying_type<MODULE_ENABLED>::type>(a));
}

int main() {
    MODULE_ENABLED status = MODULE_ENABLED::MODULE_ENABLED_FRONT_CAMERA|MODULE_ENABLED::MODULE_ENABLED_MIDDLE_CAMERA;

    std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(status) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


The warning is because you can create for example value 3 which is clearly not a valid value within the enum scope. Instead of declaring an enum why don't you just create some constexpr constants in a namespace with the same name as your current enum? E.g. namespace MODULE_ENABLED { inline constexpr std::uint8_t MODULE_ENABLED_NONE = 0;  inline constexpr std::uint8_t MODULE_ENABLED_FRONT_CAMERA  = 1; }  If you want to make a real type out of it you can also wrap the uint8_t in a struct as member and add your bitwise operators to that. (and again make constexpr constant instances of that )

@PepijnKramer The warning? What's that? I can't see there is any warning indeed.

sorry for the confusion. Your code should be fine :)

I would encapsulate a std::bitset<my_enum::end> and define the interface to use my_enum as bit indice. That way, I would not need manual values for individual members.


as the result of the said expresson not a valid value for enum class MODULE_ENABLED

That's not true, because it's not just the named enumerations that are valid values.  You can indeed OR the bit flags together as you do... it's common and safe usage.

Technically not completely true. If I remember correctly the standard says that only values smaller or equal to the highest values are assumed to be correct (e.,g values 0,1,2,3,4).  Though most compilers seem not to care too much if you stay within the bounds of the underlying type.

@PepijnKramer Thank you for the tip. Is there any reference that could help me to dig deeper in this matter?

https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.enum#8 Seems it is somewhat complicated, but only if an underlying type is not specified the compiler is free to select the smallest type that can hold the largest value (and then you could end up in overflows if you add enum values together). So I did remember there was a corner case but for this example it should all be fine (std::uint8_t can easily hold the sum of the provided bits)

@PepijnKramer: from the link you provide, "The width of the smallest bit-field large enough to hold all the values of the enumeration type is M.
It is possible to define an enumeration that has values not defined by any of its enumerators." - shows your first comment was wrong.  We're not adding enum values together, we're bitwise ORing them - the range of values you can reach that way is different (from arithmetic addition) and can always be stored in any type that can hold the individual values.

I am making a mess if am I not ;)  or-ing is a kind of adding but indeed it will never overflow the largest value.  Me bad

Do not use enum classes for "bit" like types use this instead :
#include <utility>

namespace Camera
{
struct CameraBits
{
    std::uint8_t value{ 0 };

    CameraBits operator|(CameraBits const& other) const
    {
        CameraBits result;
        result.value = value | other.value;
        return result;
    }

    CameraBits& operator|=(CameraBits const& other)
    {
        value |= other.value;
        return *this;
    }

};


inline constexpr CameraBits None{0};
inline constexpr CameraBits FrontCamera{1};
inline constexpr CameraBits RearCamera{2};

} //namespace Camera

int main()
{
    Camera::CameraBits cameras;
    cameras |= Camera::FrontCamera;
}


This may or may not be reasonable advice, but OP won't know if you don't provide any pros/cons.
